# Qual a estrutura de pastas "correta" para um projeto PHP MVC utilizando o VueJS?

Tags: php, mvc, vue.js, design-pattern

Sei que não existe uma estrutura absoluta de pastas, mas se houver uma preferência comum, já dá uma clareada no caminho.

Eu normalmente utilizo algo como:

```
-app (arquivos .php)
   -model
   -view
   -control
-public
   -js
   -css
   -images
   -index.php
```

Procurei em vários lugares mas não encontrei nenhum exemplo de aplicação PHP MVC com VueJS.
Em que pasta eu "devo/posso" iniciar `(vue-cli init ...)` o meu projeto Vue?

Comment: Ta usando algum framework no php?

Comment: Não, php puro msm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não acho que tu deveria se preocupar tanto com isso já que não ta usando nenhum outro framework junto. Por exemplo se tu for utilizar o vuejs com symfony ele vai botar dentro do diretório ./assests/vuejs ou ./assets/algumapasta, no caso do laravel vai ficar dentro de ./resources/assets/js. Por exemplo:

```
.
├── laravel
│   ├── app
│   ├── public
│   └── resources
│       └── assets
│           └── vuejs
└── symfony
    ├── assets
    │   └── vuejs
    ├── public
    └── src
```

Então se tu quiser seguier o +- o mesmo conceito dos caras vai ficar algo assim:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── control
│   ├── model
│   └── view
├── assets
│   └── vuejs
└── public
    ├── css
    ├── images
    └── js
```

[aqui](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/symfony-vuejs/tree/master/app) tem um exemplo usando com symfony e [aqui](https://github.com/dongido001/symfony-vue-twilio) também.

Com [laravel](https://github.com/anthonygore/vue-laravel-crud).

Mas se a tua aplicação em php for separada do vuejs só se comunicando por uma api restful por exemplo, o melhor seria deixar elas totalmente separadas, dessa forma:

```
.
├── backend
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── control
│   │   ├── model
│   │   └── view
│   └── public
│       ├── css
│       ├── images
│       └── js
└── frontend
    └── vuejs
```

Answer (score -2):

Cada Framework tem seu esqueleto. Se for uma aplicação SPA por exemplo você pode rodar o back-end em um servidor e o front-end em outro. Não necessariamente precisa estar dentro do esqueleto...